# How to make number in first line of file as variable?

Tags: perl, variables

I have a file with a list of number like this:

```
10
15..135
140..433
444..598
600..783
800
```

The first and last lines are always single number without "..". So the problem is that, how to edit the first and last line to be like this:

```
1..10
15..135
140..433
444..598
600..783
800..900
```

For the first line.. I need to put "1.." in front of the number IF THE NUMBER IS NOT 0. If the number is already 0, no "1.." need to be there.

For last line.. I always want to edit (in this case I add "`..900`"). Can somebody give me some idea?

Comment: So you really want a first line like `1..1`?

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -pi -e '($.==1)?s/^/1../:((eof)?s/$/..900/:1);' your_file
```

PS: This does an in place replacement of the file